# Date format in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My data:

```
[Row(ID=2887628, Date_Time='11/01/2019 05:00:00 PM'),
```

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('Date_Time',F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp('Date_Time', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a').cast('timestamp')))
```

But the answer of Date_Time is wrong:

```
[Row(ID=2887628, Date_Time=None),
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case `h` instead of upper case. See the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for correct datetime pattern usage.

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Date_Time',
    F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp('Date_Time', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').cast('timestamp'))
)
```

Your code can also be simplified. No need for using `unix_timestamp`.

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Date_Time',
    F.to_date('Date_Time', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')
)
```

Comment: How can I show the date and time rather than just date?

Comment: @LicunLiu use `to_timestamp` instead of `to_date`.